# Numbers don't repeat in the same row or column.

Tags: combinatorics

What are the total possible ways you can fill up a $5$x$5$ grid with {${1,2,3,4,5}$} such that any row or column cannot contain the same number more than once, and all 5 numbers must be used in every row and column.

What I tried :
The first row has $5!$ chances 
The second row is the derangement of the first row so D(5) 
The third row is where i struggle a little

Any help is appreciated, perhaps a general solution with an $N$x$N$ grid would be nice.

Edit 1: These are called "Latin Squares" and there is no such closed form formula for this (yet). Here is the wiki :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square

Comment: you're asking for the number of $5\times 5$ latin squares, or equivalently, the number of quasigroup structures on an $5$-element set. There's a formula for the number of $N \times N$ latin squares, but it's a bit complicated.

Comment: If you can read french language : http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/Wwwgvmm/CarreMag/aaaMaths/Latin.htm#quantite

Comment: thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Ian Wanless has lots of data about Latin squares, in particular their enumeration up to n=11. https://users.monash.edu.au/~iwanless/#LatSQs